# row-specific context menu for WPF DataGrid vs existing RowStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I am trying to add a context menu to my WPF datagrid is specific to each row, because its items need to depend on the DataContext for that row. For example "Save" might be disabled if I know the row has not been edited.

I am looking at the accepted answer for [Create contextmenus for datagrid rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200687/create-contextmenus-for-datagrid-rows) and trying to adapt it to the existing xaml I am working with, but I don't know how to use this solution on top of my existing RowStyle.

If I copy and paste the context menu code everything works, but I already have this for RowStyle:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eed3f7" />
       </Trigger>
   [...]
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

And I don't understand how to incorporate:

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"/>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've been looking at this for so long that *you can't see the wood for the trees*. In your linked answer, there is this `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
</Style>
```

You say that you can't use it because you have your own `Style` that you want to apply... but the `Style` above has only one `Setter` and so there is nothing stopping you from copying that one `Setter` into your `Style`:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" /><!--<<<<<<<<-->
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eed3f7" />
       </Trigger>
   [...]
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Alternatively, you could have based your `Style` on the `DefaultRowStyle`:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="DefaultRowStyle">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eed3f7" />
       </Trigger>
   [...]
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I was just stabbing in the dark trying to guess the right syntax as it's my first time working with WPF.