# WPF DataGridRow ContextMenu MenuItem Click Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with a context menu that is only accessible from the rows. I got the solution from [this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200687/create-contextmenus-for-datagrid-rows). I needed to tie the context menu to the rows because the click methods require a specific row to be selected. The context menu on the rows looks and works great. The problem is now the click events for the menu items aren't firing. Does anybody know how to fix this?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NetworkEntryGrid" Margin="10,10,10,0" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Install As">
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallLabelsMenuItem" Header="Labels" Click="InstallLabelsMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallATagsMenuItem" Header="A Tags" Click="InstallATagsMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallSpecialLabelsMenuItem" Header="Special Labels" Click="InstallSpecialLabelsMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallReportsMenuItem" Header="Reports" Click="InstallReportsMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallPawnTicketsMenuItem" Header="Pawn Tickets" Click="InstallPawnTicketsMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="InstallReceiptsMenuItem" Header="Receipts" Click="InstallReceiptsMenuItem_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Copy">
                            <MenuItem x:Name="CopyNameMenuItem" Header="Name" Click="CopyNameMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="CopyIpMenuItem" Header="IP" Click="CopyIpMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="CopyMacMenuItem" Header="MAC Address" Click="CopyMacMenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem x:Name="CopyVendorMenuItem" Header="Vendor" Click="CopyVendorMenuItem_Click"/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

I added a MessageBox and WriteLine commands to the click event method to be sure but they do not show up.

C#:

```
private void InstallLabelsMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Labels Clicked");
    MessageBox.Show("Labels Clicked", "Menu Item Event", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    AssignPrinter("Labels");
}
```

Comment: mark it as answer if it helps you 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `ContextMenu` as a `Resource` and reference it as a `StaticResource`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="NetworkEntryGrid" Margin="10,10,10,0" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Install As">
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallLabelsMenuItem" Header="Labels" Click="InstallLabelsMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallATagsMenuItem" Header="A Tags" Click="InstallATagsMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallSpecialLabelsMenuItem" Header="Special Labels" Click="InstallSpecialLabelsMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallReportsMenuItem" Header="Reports" Click="InstallReportsMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallPawnTicketsMenuItem" Header="Pawn Tickets" Click="InstallPawnTicketsMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="InstallReceiptsMenuItem" Header="Receipts" Click="InstallReceiptsMenuItem_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy">
                <MenuItem x:Name="CopyNameMenuItem" Header="Name" Click="CopyNameMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="CopyIpMenuItem" Header="IP" Click="CopyIpMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="CopyMacMenuItem" Header="MAC Address" Click="CopyMacMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="CopyVendorMenuItem" Header="Vendor" Click="CopyVendorMenuItem_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: This totally fixed the issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DominicJonas Any idea why this works but OP's method doesn't?