# Right click on datagrid to show context menu wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid where I would like to be able to right click, make it show a popup and capture the row it has been right clicked on. I have found something very similar here: [right click context menu for datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagridview) but they all use the `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` because they are old. I found a relatively new one which is like this:

```
if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu m = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            m.MenuItems.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem("Cut"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem("Copy"));
            m.MenuItems.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem("Paste"));

            int currentMouseOverRow = datagrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

            if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
            {
                m.MenuItems.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem(string.Format("Do something to row {0}", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
            }

            m.Show(datagrid, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        }
```

But I am getting errors on the `m.Show(datagrid, new Point(e.X, e.Y));` and `HitTest`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create contextmenus for datagrid rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200687/create-contextmenus-for-datagrid-rows)

Comment: Yes exactly what I was looking for, thanks @Keithernet